# how to redirect data on same page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a beginner in laravel. In my form, there is a search button. When I click on this search button, I want when I fill the form data, the data to be shown in the table columns below. I share the image of my view. I would be really thankful if anyone helps me.
Thanks

**Controller code:**

```
public function checkData(){
$project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
$work_package = $_POST['work_package'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$work_order = $_POST['work_order'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
$bill_type = $_POST['bill_type'];

$data = array("project_id" => $project_id, "work_package" => $work_package,
 "user_id" => $user_id, "work_order" => $work_order, "start_date" => $start_date,
 "end_date" => $end_date,"bill_type" => $bill_type);
 die('hello');
 dd($data);
```

}

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('testpage', 'OpenProjectController@index');
```

Route::post('testpage', 'OpenprojectController@checkData')->name('postData');

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAoWb.png)

Comment: I also share the image of my form "enter image description here" in the form of a URL with some code. I am stuck in a couple of days but couldn't get the solution. please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use b below to redirect to same page with data.

```
return Redirect::back()->with(['data', $data]);
```

Also,

```
return redirect()->back()->with(['data', $data]);
```

If you want to return form data, you can use `withInput` method.

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is POST the form on same method

```html
<form action="post"></form>
```

it will post the data on your method

```php
public function search(){
  return view('search')
}
```

you can access `request()` helper in your view (Which will give null if you try to access any value at first but after post it will give you posted value)

```html
<input name="order_number" value="{{ request()->order_number }}">
```

Same for the selector

```html
<select name="user_id">
   <option {{ request()->user_id == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }} value="1">user 1</option>
   <option {{ request()->user_id == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }} value="1">user 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will fill the value only when you post the data once.
before post it will keep the fields empty.